# Java Stream to Collect Entity

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a method which return User entity,

am trying to map them and collect it to Spring Core API, UserDetails.

```
User user = userRepository.findByName(userName);
       Optional.ofNullable(user)
                .map(a -> new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(a.getName(),
                        a.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>())).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The above returns `List<UserDetails>`but in my case, i want to collect it UserDetails entity (1 item) and findByName() may return NULL, in this case i need to throw custom exception.

is there any way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why do you need a `Stream` here? Don't confuse `Optional` with `Stream`s.

Comment: Considered Elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unnecessarily converting your optional to a stream. All you need to do is read the value from the optional:

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails = 
    Optional.ofNullable(user)
      .map(a -> new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(a.getName(),
                        a.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()))
      .orElse(null); //null returned if optional is empty.
```

Comment: *and `findByName()` may return NULL, in this case i need to throw custom exception*... `orElseThrow` would suit better.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is your friend.

```
User user = userRepository.findByName(userName);
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User springUser = null;
if (user != null) {
    springUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getName(),
                        user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Note that your repo shouldn't return null. It should return an Optional. That's what Optional is for: to signal that a method can return an absent value. Don't abuse Optional to replace null checks. If it returns an Optional, then you can use

```
springUser = optionalUser.map(...).orElse(null);
```